# Spring boot se lanzan validaciones sin usar @Valid

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, validación

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web hecha Spring Boot 2 y usando hibernate para persistencia y validación.

He creado una entidad con anotaciones de validación y un controlador.
P.e.

```
@Entity
public class Prueba {

   @NotNull 
   private String campo;

   @NotNull
   @Min(1)
   private Integer numero;
}

// Omito el @Service

@Controller
public class PruebaController {

    // Cosas

    @RequestMapping("/prueba")
    public String crear(@ModelAttribute Prueba prueba, BindingResult resultado, Model modelo) {

        if (resultado.hasErrors()) {
            //procesamos errores
            return "/error";
        }
        return "/ok";
    }
}
```

En teoria para validar 'prueba' deberia añadir @Valid (@ModelAttribute @Valid Prueba) pero sin añadirlo spring/hibernate lanza la validación y en el caso que no se cumpla me salta una Excepción.
Aparentemente valida sin indicarselo (@Valid) no he he leido en ningun sitio que se lance la validación de forma automática solo con incluir @NotNull, etc..

La validación que se realiza lanza una Excepcion si no se cumple, no rellena "resultado" con los errores, por lo que no puedo gestionar los errores.
Las excepciones es esta:

```
 o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Validation failed for classes [Prueba] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=campo, rootBeanClass=class Prueba, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=numero, rootBeanClass=class vdm.entidad.ContratoProducto, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
```

¿Cuál es la razón para que se valide sin @Valid y por que lanza una excepción en vez de añadirlos a "resultado"?

Existe algún sitio donde se explique todo el proceso, he leido la doc de spring / hibernate y no lo he visto.En todsos sitio dice que para validar hay que marcar con @Valid

Saludos

Comment: La excepcion ocurre antes de entrar al metodo de `crear` o  te permite alcanzar la linea de `resultado.hasErrors()`?

Comment: Pasa por resultado.hasErrors() sin dar error ni tener dentro ningun error. Despues al hacer un save (persistir) es cuando salta la Excepcion.

Answer (score 1):

El comportamiento que estas observando es el de Hibernate validando tu entidad antes de persistirla en la base de datos. [Si no me equivoco](https://thoughts-on-java.org/automatically-validate-entities-with-hibernate-validator/), `Hibernate` hecha un vistazo a las anotaciones que has colocado en las columnas de la entidad antes de tratar de persistirlas, por lo que observas excepciones en lugar de *renderear* una pagina de error.

Lo anterior sucedio ya que como no has colocado la anotacion `@Valid`, las validaciones sobre el objeto de entrada (en este caso tu entidad) no toman lugar. Consecuentemente chequear `resultado.hasErrors()` resultara en una respuesta negativa, y por ello el proceso llega al punto de tratar de persistir como explique anteriormente.

Lo correcto, para poder hacer uso de `resultado.hasErrors()`, seria que coloques `@Valid` en el objeto de entrada del controlador.